# Is it possible to re-initialize google authentiation middleware with options before calling challenge in AuthenticationManager

Tags: owin, google-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am developing an application with social logins enabled. My customers will signin using google / facebook etc...

Each customer has a separate uri to login to my application. I can get their client id and secret for google authentication. In case the values are available, can I set those values before making a request to the google auth server. I would like the customers to pay for the API requests based on their usage.

I find that in the handler, the data set in the startup middleware options are used to construct the URI. Is there any way for me to change the client id and secret before making a request to google URI for each customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default, there is no support for multi-tenancy. Hence, I have coded my own middleware that is highly configurable and solved this issue.